# Is there a standard poetic contraction for "holiest"?

Tags: contractions, poetry

Is there a standard poetic contraction for the word "holiest"?  I wish to contract it to two syllables, such that it reads "HOLE-yist".  Should this be spelled "hol'est"?  Or even "hol'iest"?

Would be very grateful for a reference to a poem where this contraction is used.

Comment: No, not really. Sorry.

Comment: "Most high", "highest" some context would help.

Comment: In his famous hymn "Praise to the Holiest in the height", Cardinal Newman evidently regarded it as a two-syllable word and didn't use any written contraction. All the verses have an 8-6-8-6 syllable pattern.

Comment: @KateBunting this is very helpful; please post this as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In his famous hymn "Praise to the Holiest in the height", Cardinal Newman evidently regarded it as a two-syllable word and didn't use any written contraction. All the verses have an 8-6-8-6 syllable pattern.